# CDO.Message does not send email

Tags: vba, cdo.message

CDO.MESSAGE does not send mail. No error but mail is not received to the email address contained in `Range("B2")`
I am tired for trying new methods. Tried with quite a few email IDs but no go.

[Image attached for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44dkp.png)

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "excel@vba.in.net"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.xyz.com"

        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Update
    End With

    strbody = "<H3>Topic Here:</H3>" & _
            "Body here<BR>"

    'Paste selected range for formatted text
    Dim cRange As Range
    Set cRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:T20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    cRange.Select
    cRange.Copy
    cRange.PasteSpecial  '???
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c4")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = """VBA Macro"" <excel@vba.in.net>"
        .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Name
        .HTMLBody = strbody
'        .send

    End With
    MsgBox ("Email has been sent successfully.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Your .send line is commented.  Are you sending it another way?

Comment: I tried even with enabling .send part. But no go.

Comment: After enabling .send what happens is-
1. A cell within the range was merged, it unmerged
2. The range showed a border like the text has been copied and need to paste somewhere
3. Email was received by the recipient but without data in the range. They only received
   3.1 Subject: Name of the workbook (as expected)
   3.2 Body: Topic Here:
                    Body here (not expected. I was expecting the ranged data below the "Topic Here:")

Comment: How much data are you trying to add to the body of your message? Can you post a sample?

Comment: Can I upload the spreadsheet here?

Comment: If you can just post a screen snip that would be great.

Comment: There was no option to upload no file nor an image. Therefore, sending the file url, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V7IJAM2gaCVHJCnyyhecyKRSG7hHEsuC

Comment: To add an image, take a snippet, copy, then edit your original question and in the body, paste.

Comment: Added image in the original question.